# Unsure why if statement causes segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this `if` statement in one of my functions that seems to return a valid result when I query it with `gdb`, but it still ends up giving me a `segfault`.

Here is the function in question:

```
/* reads the file and adds each word to the trie
   returns the number of unique words in the file */
int read_file(FILE *in, T_node *root, int *max_len)
{
   char *word = NULL;
   int num_unique = 0;
   int len;
   max_len = 0;

   if(root == NULL)
   {
      perror("Bad root");
      exit(3);
   }

   while ((word = read_long_word(in)) != NULL)
   {
      len = strlen(word);
      /************ segfault here ***********/
      if (len > *max_len)
      {
         *max_len = len;
      }
      num_unique += add_word(root, word);
   }

   return num_unique;
}
```

Here is where I am running it from:

```
/* tests file with some repeated words */
void test_read_file2(void)
{
   FILE *in = fopen("repeated.txt", "r");
   T_node *root = create_T_node();
   int max_len = 0;
   /****** segfault caused by this call *****/
   checkit_int(read_file(in, root, &max_len), 8);
   checkit_int(max_len, 19);
   free_trie(root);
   fclose(in);
}
```

And here is what I get from `gdb`:

```
27            if (len > *max_len)
(gdb) p len
$4 = 5
(gdb) p *max_len
$5 = 0
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402035 in read_file (in=0x605010, root=0x605250, 
    max_len=0x7fffffffe0dc) at fw.c:27
27            if (len > *max_len)
(gdb) p *max_len
$6 = 0
(gdb) p len > *max_len
$7 = 1
```

As you can see just above, when I print the `if` condition it returns `true` just fine, but I get a segmentation fault on that line (27) anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: `max_len = 0;` should be `*max_len = 0;`

Comment: You get a segfault because you're changing `max_len` to a null pointer, and then trying to dereference it, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, that solved it! But I don't understand when I did "p *max_len" in gdb why didn't it give me the cannot access that memory location message like it usually does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int read_file(FILE *in, T_node *root, int *max_len)
```

`max_len` is a pointer

```
max_len = 0;
```

This line makes `max_len` a null pointer.

```
*max_len = len;
```

Here you try to dereference a null pointer.

Change the iniitialization of `max_len` to

```
*max_len = 0;
```